# Scipy - Audio Processing

Tags: audio, signals, signal-processing

I looking for good tool for Audio signal processing.
e.g Speech & music analysis, identification.

Is scipy provides function for these?
Is this a good tool for Audio Signal processing?

Can you please suggest a better tool for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy provides you with the basic scientific tools, but not anything particular. A lot of the stuff in scipy is inspired by or even copyied from the basic MatLab functionality. As fas as I know there is no speech processing package but instead everything you need to build such thing, i.e. dsp lib, fft, statistics, linear algebra, even a symbol toolbox.